# Are there any FOSS/community library registries for hardware description languages?

Tags: community

One of the most objectively strong points of free/open source is the community storage of library code, where code can be scrutinized, compatibility can be maintained, and duplicated effort can be reduced. Great examples are https://crates.io/ and [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/).

When I first learned hardware description languages, I wasn't completely aware of this, and didn't think about it, but is there such a storage network for HDLs like VHDL and Verilog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only site that I've heard mentioned before is https://opencores.org/. I've never used it personally, but it's the only one that I know of.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing yet. Why?
Well why did these package repositories such as CRAN, crates, NPM, Pypi, Rubygems, Maven, etc. came to life?

I think this is natural evolution. And a succession of needs and actions. Some are:

1. the programming languages started to be used reasonably widely
2. several FOSS libraries were released
3. the emerging community felt that it was difficult to find and install these good libraries in a consistent way
4. Someone who felt this pain more acutely decided to scratch the itch and started creating a package manager, defining conventions and specs for building, installing, publishing, finding, etc. packages.
5. it felt good and caught up with the rest of the world. Or not.

I would not know where you would stand for VHDL and Verilog designs, but it could well be that you have reached "level 3" and that you could be the "someone" to start "level 4"?

Comment: Wow, that's encouraging.